# how to generate permutation at each call of function or

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have a list like `1 2 3 4 5`. I tryied to find algorithm to generate combination of all. I mean one finction will create all combinations at once or generate combination of length i at each call. How should I approach this problem in algorithmic perspective. i.e how to solve this problem ? For example;

```
list: 1 2 3 4 5
combinations:
      twos: 1 2, 1 3, 1 4, 1 5, 2 3, 2 4, 2 5, 3 4, 3 5,
                  4 5
      threes: 1 2 3, 1 2 4, 1 2 5, 1 3 4, 1 3 5, 1 4 5,
                    2 3 4, 2 3 5, 2 4 5, 3 4 5
      fourths: 1 2 3 4, 1 2 3 5, 1 3 4 5, 2 3 4 5, 
                      1 2 4 5
      not ones and not fourhs
      combinations not repatitive
```

Comment: Now permutation or combination?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command `nchoosek` in MATLAB.

```
a=[1 2 3 4 5];
combinations=nchoosek(a,2)
```

This will give all possible ways to select two elements out of 5.

Answer (score 0):

One classical solution to this problem is, for combinations of size i, initialize an array to `A = [1, 2, ... , i]` and then do the following loop:

```
While A[i] <= n

  1. Print the current value of A
  2. For j = i to 1
       If A[j] < n - i + j then break
  3. Set A[j] += 1
  4. For k = j+1 to i
       Set A[k] = A[k-1] + 1
```